# For an integral curve on a smooth manifold, can the interval on which it is defined be non-open?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm studying Professor Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (Second Edition) and Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds (Second Edition), (ISM and IRM, respectively).
In ISM Chapter 3 section Velocity Vectors of Curves on page 68, he defines the domain
of a curve to be an interval $J$, most of the time open, but sometimes with one or two
endpoints. The rest of the section (defining velocity vectors of smooth curves) makes
perfect sense with any kind of interval $J$.

Then we get to ISM Chapter 9, the section on Integral Curves on page 206, in which we deal
with "differentiable" (I assume that is to be taken
to be the same as smooth) curves, but no mention is made of what kind of interval
they are defined on. But that's fine; I can deal with them being defined on intervals
with zero, one or two endpoints, up until page 212 when a **maximal integral curve** is
defined as "one that cannot be extended to an integral curve on any larger *open*
interval (emphasis added)". This is followed by the **Fundamental Theorem on Flows**, in which property (a) states that
$$\theta^{(p)}\colon\mathscr{D}^{(p)}\to M$$
is the "unique smooth maximal integral curve of $V$ starting at $p$." [In this context,
$\mathscr{D}^{(p)}$ is an open interval.]

So now I have a question. The definition of maximal integral curve and the theorem work
fine if integral curves are defined only on open intervals. But if they can be defined
on intervals with one or two endpoints, then I imagine there could be a problem where
there were two different integral curves, one defined on an open interval and one defined
on that interval plus an endpoint, say, having the same values on the open interval, but
not being extendable any further. Then both curves would have to be considered to be
maximal, thus breaking uniqueness. So here's the question finally. This theorem is for smooth manifolds without
boundary. Is that sufficient to show that what I just described can't happen? I know
of two ways that an integral curve might not be extendable: if it blows up at the
endpoint or if it runs into the boundary. If there is no boundary and if it can be
extended to an endpoint, then it is not blowing up at the endpoint, and it can be
extended further (waving hands furiously here). So is there any other way that an
integral curve can be prevented from extending? If not, can I safely assume that
maximal integral curves (into smooth manifolds without boundary) are necessarily
defined on open intervals?

The reason I mentioned IRM is I also would like to know if assuming that maximal
integral curves are always defined on open intervals will get me into trouble
in IRM.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically correct about extendability. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold without boundary. Due to the uniform time of existence of solutions for compact $K \subset M$, you can show that if a solution $y$ to $y'(t) = X(y(t))$, $y(0) = y_0$ exists on an interval $(a, b)$ and there is a compact $K \subset M$ such that $y(t) \in K$ for all $t \in (a, b)$, then there exist $a_1 < a$ and $b_1 > b$ such that $y(t)$ solves the ode for $t \in (a_1, b_1)$.

Now suppose $I = (a^*, b^*)$ is the maximal open interval on which the solution $y$ exists and that $b^* < \infty$. By a sequential compactness argument using the above result, you can show that if $K \subset M$ is compact, then there exists $t_K \in I$ such that $y(t) \notin K$ for $t \geq t_K$. Thus $y(t) \to \infty$ as $t \nearrow b^*$.

A readable but terse treatment for the case when $M$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be found on page 80 of https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf